# How can I fix a dropdown submenu not to roll back in once clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lately I have been struggling to get a dropdown fixed. It works fine except when I add a sub-menu to the dropdown and you click on it, everything will roll back in. I'm sure it has something to do with the javascript deactivating the dropdown effect once clicked. Here is a short example:

https://gyazo.com/bbe7dd3592b4d647cfe3f97a62c538d1

Code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // insert toggle button
  jQuery(".advanced-sidebar-nav").each(function() {
    jQuery(".menu-item-has-children", jQuery(this)).each(function() {
      // insert toggle button
      jQuery("> a", jQuery(this)).append(
        '<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span>'
      );

      // add indent
      var depth = jQuery(this).parents(".menu-item-has-children").length;
      jQuery("ul li a", jQuery(this)).attr(
        "style",
        "padding-left:" + (depth + 2) * 20 + "px !important"
      );

      // open nav menu toggle
      if (jQuery("ul", jQuery(this)).css("display") == "block") {
        jQuery(".advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle", jQuery(this)).addClass(
          "advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle-open"
        );
      }
    });
  });
  jQuery(".advanced-sidebar-nav").on(
    "click",
    ".dropdown > a:first-child",
    function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const self = $(this).find(".advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle");


      jQuery(".advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open").each(
        function() {
          $(this).find(".advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle").parent("a").removeClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open").siblings("ul").slideUp(300);
          $(this).find(".advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle").not(self).removeClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle-open");
        }
      );

      jQuery(self).toggleClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle-open");

      if (jQuery(self).hasClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle-open")) {
        jQuery(self)
          .parent("a")
          .addClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open")
          .siblings("ul")
          .slideDown(300);

      } else {
        jQuery(self)
          .parent("a")
          .removeClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open")
          .siblings("ul")
          .slideUp(300);
      }
    }
  );

});
```

```css
.advanced-sidebar-nav ul,
.advanced-sidebar-nav ul ul {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  list-style: none;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav .advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -12px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav .advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle:before,
.advanced-sidebar-nav .advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav .advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle:before {}

.advanced-sidebar-nav .advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f105";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav .advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle.advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle-open {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav .advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle.advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle-open:before {}

.advanced-sidebar-nav .advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle.advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle-open:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: none;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav ul li:hover {
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav ul li.current-menu-item>a,
.advanced-sidebar-nav ul li.current-menu-ancestor>a {
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav ul li.current-menu-ancestor>ul {
  display: block;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav ul li:before,
.advanced-sidebar-nav ul li:after {
  display: none;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav ul a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  line-height: 1.4 !important;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 15px 20px !important;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms;
  transition: all 100ms;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav ul a:hover,
.advanced-sidebar-nav ul a.advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open {
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav.advanced-sidebar-nav-default .advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle {}

.advanced-sidebar-nav.advanced-sidebar-nav-default .advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle:before,
.advanced-sidebar-nav.advanced-sidebar-nav-default .advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle:after {}

.advanced-sidebar-nav.advanced-sidebar-nav-default ul {
  background-color: #dd4b39;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav.advanced-sidebar-nav-default ul ul {}

.advanced-sidebar-nav.advanced-sidebar-nav-default ul li.current-menu-item>a,
.advanced-sidebar-nav.advanced-sidebar-nav-default ul li.current-menu-ancestor>a {
  color: #000 !important;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav.advanced-sidebar-nav-default ul a {
  color: #000 !important;
}

.advanced-sidebar-nav.advanced-sidebar-nav-default ul a:hover,
.advanced-sidebar-nav.advanced-sidebar-nav-default ul a.advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open {
  color: #008edc !important;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=advanced-sidebar-nav.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="advanced-sidebar-nav advanced-sidebar-nav-default">
  <ul id="menu-sidebar-menu" class="advanced-sidebar-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-4701" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4701"><a href="#">Laptops<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-4943" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4943"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/laptops/celeron/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Celeron</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-5103" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-5103"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/laptops/amd/" style="padding-left:40px !important">AMD</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4696" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4696"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/laptops/i3/" style="padding-left:40px !important">i3</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4697" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4697"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/laptops/i5/" style="padding-left:40px !important">i5</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4698" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4698"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/laptops/i7/" style="padding-left:40px !important">i7</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4695" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4695"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/laptops/game-laptops/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Game laptops</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-4703" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4703"><a href="#">Computers<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-4965" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4965"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/computers/desktop/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Desktop</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4709" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4709"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/computers/tower/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Tower</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4710" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4710"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/computers/workstation/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Workstation</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4708" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4708"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/computers/game-computers/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Game computers</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-5011" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-5011"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/servers/">Servers</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4704" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4704"><a href="#">Monitoren<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-4890" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4890"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/monitoren/17/" style="padding-left:40px !important">17″</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4712" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4712"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/monitoren/19/" style="padding-left:40px !important">19″</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-5052" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-5052"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/monitoren/20/" style="padding-left:40px !important">20″</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4713" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4713"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/monitoren/22/" style="padding-left:40px !important">22″</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-5016" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-5016"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/monitoren/23/" style="padding-left:40px !important">23″</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4714" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4714"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/monitoren/24/" style="padding-left:40px !important">24″</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4715" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4715"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/monitoren/27/" style="padding-left:40px !important">27″</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4716" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4716"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/monitoren/32/" style="padding-left:40px !important">32″</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-4705" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4705"><a href="#">Netwerkapparatuur<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-4721" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4721"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/netwerkapparatuur/switchers/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Switches</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4718" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4718"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/netwerkapparatuur/nas/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Nas</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4722" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4722"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/netwerkapparatuur/thin-clients/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Thin clients</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4717" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4717"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/netwerkapparatuur/accespoints/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Access Points</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4719" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4719"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/netwerkapparatuur/repeaters/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Repeaters</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4720" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4720"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/netwerkapparatuur/routers/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Routers</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4781" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4781"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/netwerkapparatuur/netwerk-accessoires/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Netwerk accessoires</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-5151" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-5151"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/netwerkapparatuur/kvm-switches/" style="padding-left:40px !important">KVM Switches</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-4706" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4706"><a href="#">Hard Drive<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-4725" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4725"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/hard-drive/ssd-drive/" style="padding-left:40px !important">SSD Drive</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4726" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4726"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/hard-drive/ssd-m-2/" style="padding-left:40px !important">SSD M.2</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4727" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4727"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/hard-drive/ssd-msata/" style="padding-left:40px !important">SSD Msata</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4723" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4723"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/hard-drive/sata-2-5/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Sata 2.5″</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4724" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4724"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/hard-drive/sata-3-5/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Sata 3.5″</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-4707" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4707"><a href="#" class="advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open">Accessoires<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle-open"></span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
        <li id="menu-item-4785" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4785"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/accessoires/beveiliging/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Beveiliging</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4729" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children menu-item-4729"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/accessoires/kabels/" style="padding-left:40px !important" class="">Kabels<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
          <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
            <li id="menu-item-4834" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4834"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/accessoires/kabels/displayport/" style="padding-left:60px !important">DisplayPort</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-4879" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4879"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/accessoires/kabels/usb-kabels/" style="padding-left:60px !important">USB Kabels</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-4728" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4728"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/accessoires/adapters/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Adapters</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4730" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4730"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/accessoires/memory/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Memory</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4850" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4850"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/accessoires/tablet-hoesjes/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Tablet Hoesjes</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4868" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4868"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/accessoires/reiniging/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Reiniging</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4873" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4873"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/accessoires/usb-hubs/" style="padding-left:40px !important">USB Hubs</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-4757" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children menu-item-4757"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/randapparatuur/">Randapparatuur<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-4759" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4759"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/accessoires/pcmcia-express-card/" style="padding-left:40px !important">PCMCIA &amp; Express Card</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4758" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children menu-item-4758"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/randapparatuur/toetsenborden/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Toetsenborden<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-4824" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4824"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/randapparatuur/toetsenborden/draadloos/" style="padding-left:60px !important">Draadloos</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-4825" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4825"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/randapparatuur/toetsenborden/bedraad/" style="padding-left:60px !important">Bedraad</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-4882" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children menu-item-4882"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/randapparatuur/muizen/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Muizen<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-4883" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4883"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/randapparatuur/muizen/bedraad-muizen/" style="padding-left:60px !important">Bedraad</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-4884" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4884"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/randapparatuur/muizen/draadloos-muizen/" style="padding-left:60px !important">Draadloos</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-4763" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children menu-item-4763"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/printers/">Printers<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-4764" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-4764"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/printers/verbruiks-artikelen/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Verbruiks artikelen</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-5154" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children menu-item-5154"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/telefonie/">Telefonie<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-5155" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-5155"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/telefonie/vaste-telefonie/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Vaste Telefonie</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-5127" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-5127"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/mobiele-telefonie/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Mobiele Telefonie</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-5158" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-5158"><a href="http://projecten.jumsum.nl/adtcomputers/product-category/telefonie/accessoires-telefonie/" style="padding-left:40px !important">Accessoires</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to share the CSS too

Comment: If you use a simplistic example to tell us your problem, why don't you use the same example ( html struncture ) in the code you share ? i cannot replicate your problem

Comment: @Nimsrules I will post that too, thank you.

Comment: @MihaiT Sorry, my bad! https://gyazo.com/bbe7dd3592b4d647cfe3f97a62c538d1

Comment: Please, share it here. Preferably in a code snipper.

Comment: I have added CSS in the thread.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, I'm sorry. What happens when you click on an item in the drop-down menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix you code, you toggle all open classes instead of closest dropdown menu. You can see how i change your click dropdown, first to check if menu is open then do something with closest child. Link to fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/ecs40bfv/50/](https://jsfiddle.net/b62jhkry/58/)

Edit: click on a head submenu item all other head submenu items closes

```
jjQuery(document).ready(function() {
// insert toggle button
jQuery(".advanced-sidebar-nav").each(function() {
    jQuery(".menu-item-has-children", jQuery(this)).each(function() {
        // insert toggle button 
        jQuery("> a", jQuery(this)).append(
            '<span class="advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle"></span>'
        );

      // add indent
      var depth = jQuery(this).parents(".menu-item-has-children").length;
      jQuery("ul li a", jQuery(this)).attr(
          "style",
          "padding-left:" + (depth + 2) * 20 + "px !important"
      );
      jQuery("ul li", jQuery(this)).addClass(
      "level-2");

        // open nav menu toggle
        if (jQuery("ul", jQuery(this)).css("display") == "block") {
            jQuery(".advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle", jQuery(this)).addClass(
                "advanced-sidebar-nav-toggle-open"
            );
        }
    });
});
jQuery(".advanced-sidebar-nav").on(
    "click",
    ".dropdown > a:first-child",
    function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();      

    var isCurrentDropdownOpen = $(this).hasClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open");
       // helper to find dropdown 
       var parentListItem = $(this).closest("li");
       // dropdown list 
       var dropdownItem = parentListItem.children("ul");

       var isSecondLevel = parentListItem.hasClass("level-2");

       if(isCurrentDropdownOpen){
                dropdownItem.slideUp(300); 

          // check if child is open
     var nestedDropdown = parentListItem.find('.sub-menu .advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open');

     if(nestedDropdown[0]){
     parentListItem.find('.sub-menu').slideUp(300);
     parentListItem.find('.sub-menu .advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open').removeClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open");
     }
       } else {
                dropdownItem.slideDown(300);     

          // when opening new check if level one menu is still open
          if(!isSecondLevel){
     var nestedDropdown = $("#menu-sidebar-menu").find('.advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open').not($("level-2"));
     var parent = nestedDropdown.closest("li").children("ul").slideUp(300)
              $(".advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open").not($("level-2")).removeClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open")
            }
       }

      $(this).toggleClass("advanced-sidebar-nav-menu-open");



    }
);

});
```

Comment: This worked, but is it also possible that when I click on a head submenu item all other head submenu items closes? Thank you for your help, really appreciated.

Comment: I just edit my solution to close all items... You can check.